# How can I get intellisense in PHP/Eclipse on custom objects pulled out of array in foreach loop?

Tags: php, eclipse, intellisense, code-completion, type-hinting

I have a collection of **custom objects** (Podcast) in an array.

When I use a **foreach** loop to iterate through this collection, I don't have **code completion** on the variable that contains the object pulled out of the collection (as I would in C#/VisualStudio for instance).

**Is there a way to give PHP a type hint so that Eclipse knows the type of the object being pulled out of the collection so it can show me the methods on that object in intellisense?**

[image]

```
<?php

$podcasts = new Podcasts();
echo $podcasts->getListHtml();

class Podcasts {
    private $collection = array();

    function __construct() {
        $this->collection[] = new Podcast('This is the first one');
        $this->collection[] = new Podcast('This is the second one');
        $this->collection[] = new Podcast('This is the third one');
    }

    public function getListHtml() {
        $r = '';
        if(count($this->collection) > 0) {
            $r .= '<ul>';
            foreach($this->collection as $podcast) {
                $r .= '<li>' . $podcast->getTitle() . '</li>';
            }
            $r .= '</ul>';
        }       
        return $r;
    }
}

class Podcast {

    private $title;

    public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }
    public function setTitle($value) {  $this->title = $value;}

    function __construct($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

}

?>
```

## Addendum

Thanks, Fanis, I updated my FOREACH template to include that line automatically:

```
if(count(${lines}) > 0) {
    foreach(${lines} as ${line}) {
        /* @var $$${var} ${Type} */

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Good stuff :) Good usage of templates too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, try:

```
foreach($this->collection as $podcast) {
    /* @var $podcast Podcast */
    $r .= '<li>' . $podcast->getTitle() . '</
}
```

It's been a while since I used Eclipse but I recall it used to work there too.

Comment: You're welcome! Just fyi, some IDEs may require a proper docblock, ie double asterisks: `/** @var ... */`

Answer (score 0):

This might help some other people from the internet looking for a more succint solution to this problem.

My solution requieres PHP7 or higher. The idea is to map the array with an anonymous function and take advantage of type-hinting.

```
  $podcasts = getPodcasts();
  $listItems = array_map(function (Podcast $podcast) {
      return "<li>" . $podcast->getTitle() . "</li>";
  }, $podcasts);
  $podcastsHtml = "<ul>\n" . implode("\n", $listItems) . "\n</ul>";
```

In most cases a `foreach` can be converted into an `array_map`, it simply takes a little bit of paradigm shift towards *functional programming*.

If you use Laravel (I am sure other frameworks have Collections too) you could even chain these array maps with array filters and other functional stuff like this:

```
$html = "<ul>" . collect($podcasts)
  ->filter(function (Podcast $p) { return $p !== null; }) // filtering example
  ->map(function (Podcast $p) { return "<li>".$p->getTitle()."</li>"; }) // mapping
  ->implode("\n") . "</ul>";
```

In plain php chaining those array functions looks pretty uggly...

But there you go! a native way of type hinting your array iterations.